# Minimum number of clues for a sudoku puzzle

Tags: sudoku

In a sudoku puzzle, what is the absolute minimum number of clues that must be given to specify a layout with a unique solution? Is one in each row, column, and box (9 total) necessary or sufficient?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a standard $9 \times 9$ sudoku, the minimum is $17$ squares.  It had long been known that at least $16$ were required and that $17$ was sufficient.  [This article](https://www.technologyreview.com/2012/01/06/188520/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/) closes the gap.