# What is the fewest number of clues on a rotationally symmetrical sudoku grid with a unique solution?

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, grid-deduction, optimization, sudoku

[It is known](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100/minimum-number-of-squares-for-a-sudoku-puzzle) that the minimum number of clues a sudoku must have to have a unique solution is 17. But on every website I've seen for them, I haven't found any that are rotationally symmetrical.

I once saw a puzzle in a book which only had 19 clues and was rotationally symmetrical, but I don't remember whether the solver I ran it through said that there was a unique solution or not. My question is, what is the minimum number of already-filled-in squares that a *rotationally symmetrical* Sudoku must have in order to have a unique solution?

Note: by rotationally symmetrical, I'm referring to it in the standard sense that if a clue appears in one position, a clue will also appear in the position opposite it on the board.

Comment: rotationally symmetric how, just the center square stops it from being symmetric

Comment: The center square is symmetrical with itself.

Comment: then it isn't a valid sudoku, all 9 digits must occur exactly once, any symmetry (besides 360°) would require a number to occur twice

Comment: By rotationally symmetrical, I mean the positions of the clues can be rotated 180 degrees and will overlap itself perfectly.

Comment: still the center square can't be 180° rotational symmetrical, and the squares on the sides can't be part of that

Comment: @ratchetfreak why do you think the center can't be symmetric? Like Joe said, it is *trivially* symmetric.

Comment: @kevin for example the number at 5,1 must also be at 5,9 (1 based index) this immediately violates the sudoku invariant

Comment: They don't have to be the *same* number. The only thing that's rotationally symmetrical is that the square *is* filled in.

Comment: @ratchetfreak I see, you mean the center *row*, *column*, and *3x3*. Joe and I interpreted your statement as saying the center (5,5) itself was breaking the symmetry.

Comment: @JoeZ. you should probably clarify that in the question.

Comment: @Kevin Done and done.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Minimum_number_of_givens

Answer (score 10):

[This book](http://books.google.ca/books?id=U6RpAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA111) appears to have a puzzle with only 18 clues that is rotationally symmetrical.

```
7 2 . | . . . | . . .
. 5 . | . . 9 | . . .
. . . | . 3 8 | . . .
------+-------+-------
. . . | 4 . . | 5 . .
. . 3 | . . . | 9 . .
. . 1 | . . 3 | . . .
------+-------+-------
. . . | 2 5 . | . . .
. . . | 6 . . | . 3 .
. . . | . . . | . 1 9
```

But I still don't know if a rotationally symmetrical 17 exists.

Comment: I am totally bluffed, because these numbers are as well the first 18 digits of `PI`

Comment: @WaKai, At first blush that seems interesting, but the specific digits are arbitrary, that is, if we changed the two `1`s to `3`s, and the four `3`s to `1`s, it would still work, without being the first 18 digits of PI.