# Minimum amount of clues for a 16x16 sudoku

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, optimization, sudoku

I know that [17 is the minimum for a standard 9x9 (3x3 squares)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100/minimum-number-of-clues-for-a-sudoku-puzzle), but what about a 16x16 (4x4 squares) sudoku?

Comment: When you say 3x3 and 4x4, do you mean 9x9 (standard) and 16x16 (what's in the title)?

Comment: Of possible interest is Wikipedia's "Mathematics of Sudoku" section [Sudokus of other sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Sudokus_of_other_sizes).

Comment: The answer is here: http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/minimum-number-of-clues-16x16-and-higher-t1174.html

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, the smallest number of clues found for a 16x16 sudoku (with 4x4 squares) is 55. It has not been proven that this is the smallest number, but no one's found a better one yet. I suspect that less research into a minimum number has occurred for the larger variants because they are less common and would require more computing power to brute-force.

References:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_Sudoku#Sudokus_of_other_sizes)

> 16×16(4×4) Sudoku: At least one puzzle with 55 clues has been created. It is not known if this is the fewest possible.

The example [55-clue Sudoku](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873102235)