# Minimum number of clues required for a 16 x 16 Sudoku

Tags: mathematics, sudoku

It is well-known that the minimum number of clues that completely specify a 9 x 9 Sudoku is 17. What is the minimum number of clues required for a 16 x 16 Sudoku whose cells contain one of the integers 1 to 9, or the letters a to g?

Comment: Duplicate of https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89036/minimum-amount-of-clues-for-a-16x16-sudoku. In the [linked answer](http://forum.enjoysudoku.com/minimum-givens-on-larger-puzzles-t4801.html), 55 is the smallest found.

Comment: @eyl327 Indeed, 55 is so far minimum (https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4873102235). Not verified to be least possible though. Worth revisiting and either proving or improving.